# Android "permanent" superuser permission for an app?

Tags: android, process, runtime, exec, root

To clarify, I use this code to get superuser permission for my app so I can access root and whatnot:

```
    public String runProcess(String[] functs) {

    DataOutputStream dos;
    DataInputStream dis;
    StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer("");
    String tempInput;
    Process process;

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(functs);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        dis = new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());

        for (String command : functs) {
            dos.writeBytes(command + "\n");
            dos.flush();

            while ((tempInput = dis.readLine()) != null)
                contents.append(tempInput + "\n");

        }

        dos.writeBytes("exit\n");
        dos.flush();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return contents.toString();

}
```

And although it works just fine, whenever I call `runProcess(new String[] { "su", "-c", "some other command" });` it always asks for superuser permission. I see a lot of root apps on the market who just have to gain superuser permission once at each startup of the app, but I don't think I'd need to ask the user for superuser permission every single time the app calls an function that requires SU. So my question would be, how would I prompt the user to give me SU permission once at the startup of an app without having to continually ask for it for every SU-related action?

EDIT: I know I could run my method/the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() method without typing "su" in it every time but that only works with non-su related actions (i.e. exec("ps") or exec("ls"). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use my Library which does this.

https://code.google.com/p/roottools/

Also, if you don't want to use the library the source is available so you can just rip out my code and use it in your application.

Here is a link to the source:

https://code.google.com/p/roottools/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FStable%2FRootTools-sdk3-generic%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fstericson%2FRootTools

Comment: I don't see where this answers his questions, just provides tools, can you be more specific?

Comment: hi, does it prevent the window asking to gain superuser permission ? does it work with kitkat (4.4.2) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for the permission from a "superUser" app which is already running in your device, you just need the following code in your main java file.

```
try {
        process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(su);
    }

catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Yes, no need to mention that the device has to be already rooted!!!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you open a console asking for root access, i.e. start it with `su`, the corresponding super user app will either prompt you or allow/deny it, if you checked something like "Don't ask me again" on the previous prompt.

If you only want to have ask (the super user app) once, you will have to keep your root console open, by not calling `dos.writeBytes("exit\n");`.
Then keep this session in a background thread and use it when necessary.

So either make sure the user checks "Don't ask me again" on the first prompt or keep the session open.